# Logical and physical entities relation in OWL ontology

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology

I am creating an ontology that describes operating system components and I've run into a problem where I need to relate logical concepts with their physical counterparts but I can't imagine the exact structure and I do not understand why there is a conflict:

I have the following structure:

```
Daemon
File
   FixedFile
   TemporaryFile
   UpdatableFile
   ConfigFile
```

This structure seems correct as there are files of different type. But when I add that a Daemon has a file on disk - I can not say `hasFileOnDisk exactly 1 File` because daemon can not be a config file, and on the other hand, `ConfigFile` can be either Fixed,Updatable or even Temporary.

How do I relate that Daemon's hasFileOnDisk can not be `ConfigFile` and `ConfigFile` may be temporary,updatable or fixed but they are all files and inherit file data property `fileName`?

[image: file type and daemon ontology] [editable drawing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-2xhhL1p3OtYUlWNF90SjZhUTA/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem cannot be resolved by just using inheritance relationshps between entities. You need to use other means to put constraint on  hasFileOnDisk argument, for example disjoint classes.

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="NonConfigFile">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#File"/>
  <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="#ConfigFile"/>
</owl:Class>
```